# Unable to login using NFS rootfs

Tags: login

I have a custom board running kernel 3.2, and I'm trying booting using a remote rootfs. I've setup the kernel command line properly, and I'm able to reach the login prompt. This is where things get tricky: it accepts none of my logins (the default is just 'root', without password), but is keeps telling me "Login incorrect".

If I try to login as root, it simply times out, without asking for my password. If I try any other login, it asks me to input a password. Both cases fail with the same message.

I've checked the `/etc` files, but didn't find anything suspicious. I use this very same rootfs to boot from my system's flash memory. Any ideas on what might be wrong?

Comment: What distro? How is network setup?

Comment: It is a custom one, based on Texas Instruments' Angstrom distro. My board is connected to the host via Ethernet cable.

Comment: Do you have `squashroot` set on export or mount?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Knowing it is quite old question but I have encountered the same problem, so may be it'll help somebody...

The resolution is in NFS share provider.

NFS share has a protection for external root users to not mess up shared resource. So access from remote root is not the same as access from local root. 
As authentication is very sensitive for such "almost root access" cases it does not allow to login as root from "almost root" files.
In order to bypass this, NFS shall be shared with following option in /etc/export:

```
no_root_squash
```

eg:

```
/srv/nfs 127.0.0.1(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash,insecure)
```